# Is this version of the halting problem NONELEMENTARY?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, computability, halting-problem

**Input**: A TM $M$ and an integer $k$.

**Output**: Yes if $M$ halts within $2\uparrow\uparrow k$ steps (where $\uparrow\uparrow$ is [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) (iterated exponentiation)).

---

Intuitively, it seems like this has to be NONELEMENTARY (and its decidability is immediate) from the undecidability of the halting problem.

I'm asking because:

1. I'm not sure what's interesting about the [ELEMENTARY/NONELEMENTARY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY) classes. (Why do people care about them as opposed to, say, all problems solvable in $2\uparrow\uparrow n$ time?)
2. I'm not sure why [all the examples I've seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_problem) of NONELEMENTARY are complex and not directly using the halting problem.

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing the answer is yes. The Time Hierarchy Theorem is enough to say that your problem cannot be solved in time $$o\left(\frac{2\uparrow \uparrow k}{2 \uparrow \uparrow {(k-1)}}\right), $$ and thus also not in time $o(2 \uparrow \uparrow {(k-1)})$, which rules out ELEMENTARY.

Comment: @BernardoSubercaseaux but is it clear that the problem cannot be solved in faster runtime? The hierarchy tells us that *there exist* problems that can be solved in $2\uparrow\uparrow n$ but not $o(\frac{2\uparrow\uparrow n}{2\uparrow\uparrow (n-1)})$, but it doesn't tell us that this is one of these problems.

Comment: That's fair, but the problem you gave is *complete* for that class, so you can show that solving it faster would enable you to solve any problem in that class faster. Alternately, you can see that the detail of the proof of the time hierarchy theorem gives basically that problem as a witness.

Comment: Cody is spot on! you're right (@NO) that if you just look at the statement of the THT then what I said doesn't follow immediately, but most standard proofs work exactly by taking that problem and showing that you can't decide it faster. In that sense, a rough interpretation of the THT is that you cannot decide whether a TM halts in $f(n)$ steps on a given input of size $n$ substantially faster than by simulating the $f(n)$ steps...